# When do SSIS Connections occur?

Tags: ssis, ssis-connection-manager

**Do SSIS ConnectionManagers attempt to make their connections on package start, or when the connection is first used?**

If it's the latter, I can use failure transitions to handle connection failures within the package, but if it's the former then I have to do it externally.

I can assume that they'd design it with the latter, but I can't find it in the documentation anywhere easily searchable/accessible.

Comment: I've removed the `sql-server` tag, since this question has nothing to do with any particular database engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends and can be controlled.
With the default setting of `DelayValidation=false` property, SSIS engine at package start tries to connect (validate) all Connection Managers and tasks with metadata and which use Connection Managers like Data Flows etc.
If you set `DelayValidation=true` on the Connection Manager itself and all relevant tasks, then the first connection on the Connection Manager for the validation would be executed right before the task is executed. This is quite helpful if you use expressions on Connection Manager properties, like dynamic connection string, and before package execution it cannot be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

In `SSIS`,it always try to validate `connection manager` at the `package` start time.
Once the `SSIS package` start, it first validate for all `parameter`, `variable` and `connection manager` etc.